# Select-string with Regex and split/output to multiple files

Tags: regex, powershell, while-loop, select-string

Good day everyone

Would like to seek advise on what i did wrong on the select string/regex. when regex with the pattern of  `'(?m)(abc)(.*?)(--- End ---)'` was tested on Notepad++, it works(the fields were highlighted correctly) but somehow when i placed it inside Powershell to execute, it return null result.

If i were to change the regex to `'(?m)(abc)(.*?)'`, it will fetch the whole content from Line1 to Line12.

I want to capture and be able to split the result into 3 result files 
File1 - (Content from Line1 to Line4)
File2 - (Content Line5 to Line8)
File3 - (Content Line9 to Line12

```
Broken Command that i used:
While (line is not equal to end of file) {
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Pscript\test-script.txt" | ForEach {
$getctnt = Get-Content $_.FullName
$getctnt | Select-String -Pattern '(?m)(abc)(.*?)(--- End ---)' | Out-File .\result$a.txt
$a++
}
}

Content of the Test-script.txt:
Line1       abc
Line2       content1
Line3       conten2
Line4       --- End ---
Line5       abc
Line6       content1
Line7       content2
Line8       --- End ---
Line9       abc
Line10      content1
Line11      content2
Line12      --- End ---
```

Comment: please, edit your post to show the EXACT content of the input text file. what you show is unlikely to be correct  since you don't have any `BBB` that your regex shows.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your attempt stems from not reading `Test-script.txt` correctly. When you run the command `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch, the file is read in as an array of strings. When that is piped into `Select-String`, the command will only process one line at a time and know nothing about the previous or next lines. If you implement the `-Raw` switch, it will read in the file as one string. Then you can pipe into `Select-String` and be able to match newline characters. With that said, you will need to enable the single line modifier (`?s`) for `.` to match `\n` and `\r` characters. Since you have multiple matches for the same regex pattern, you need to add the `-AllMatches` switch.

```
$getctnt = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw
$selections = $getctnt | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)(abc)(.*?)(--- End ---)' -AllMatches
```

`$selections` will now contain an array of `MatchInfo` objects that you can iterate or index based on your requirements. The following is how you access those values.

```
$selections.Matches # For the MatchInfo objects
$selections.Matches.Value # For the matched values
```

Since you used multiple parentheses sets, you have created 4 capture groups (0,1,2,3) and three total matches. I do not know if that was your intention, but they are also accessible. To easily access them, you can iterate over your 3 `MatchInfo` objects (three total matches).

```
$selections.Matches | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Groups[0] # Each full regex match
    $_.Groups[1] # Capture group 1: (abc)
    $_.Groups[2] # Capture group 2: (.*?)
    $_.Groups[3] # Capture group 3: (--- End ---)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
(?i)[\s\S]*?(?:.*---\s*end\s*---\s*)
```

or

```
(?i)[\s\S]*?.*---\s*end\s*---\s*
```

might be OK to look into.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Sc9qTn/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Sc9qTn/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is to break the file into an array of 4-line chunks, then this will do the job. it uses the `-ReadCount` parameter of `Get-Content` to read the file in groups of lines.

this presumes your chunks are always 4 lines, tho. [*grin*]

```
@'
abc
content_1
content_1b
--- End ---
def
content_2
content_2b
--- End ---
ghi
content_3
content_3b
--- End ---
'@ | Set-Content 'C:\Temp\StevL.txt'

$InStuff = Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\Temp\StevL.txt -ReadCount 4


$InStuff[0]
```

output ...

```
abc
content_1
content_1b
--- End ---
```